Django Manifest with Elastic Beanstalk Docker Platform
I have my application running on Elastic Beanstalk with Docker Platform and I am using my own nginx container. Recently for serving static files I used Manifest django tool which is successfully running but after deploying this tool I am getting this on my web


I wanna tell you that the staticfiles.json is perfectly being created in my staticfiles folder and the new versions of my static files are perfectly being generated. Here is my settings.py

And here is my urls.py

I even tried not in if statement cuz my app holds
DEBUG-False
on elastic beanstalk.
The logs are saying nothing - Please HELP!!!
